# How to send/receive data using bluetooth on Samsung Artik?

Tags: bash, bluetooth, terminal, fedora

I received a Samsung Artik5 Development Board the other day, and I've been trying to do some things with it.

Thing is I'm pretty new to Bash / Fedora, so I'm kinda lost.

I've managed to discover, pair and connect my bluetooth device to my Board using bluetoothctl but now I don't know what to do next, I've tried to use obexfs, but it seems the shell won't recognize that command.

Can anybody give me a hint of what to do next? I want to be able to send at least a character to my bluetooth device.

Thanks.

Comment: GUI progress bar variant is `bluetooth-sendto --device=<device_address> filename`. But that does need the user interaction & X server running...

Comment: I've tried downloading openobex.armv7hl and obexd.armv7hl. But it isn't working yet.

Comment: @Wazowski where you able to send the files using bluetooth?

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up doing something completely different.